# windows 8 tablet battery died while recording video, the file is lost

Tags: windows, windows-8, video, battery, file-recovery

I was recording a video with a Windows 8 tablet and after 2 hours the battery died. When I got back home and charged the tablet, the video was not there. There are other videos in the camera roll folder, but not this one. I hoped there would be like an 'unfinished file' at least, something like when you're downloading a file and the connection drops there's still this `.part` or `.filepart` file.

Is there any way to restore it?

The closest thing I found on the Internet is this http://forums.windowscentral.com/nokia-lumia-920/207357-battery-died-while-recording-video.html, but I don't have any extra files there, not even corrupted ones. Should I search for some temporary location?

Please advise

**UPDATE** okay so it looks like  1 second of video takes 1 MB of storage space. 2 hours would be roughly be 60*60*2 = 7.2GB of data. I've scanned the filesystem and can't see any file that big anywhere

A file that big had to be on the hard drive, there's no way it would fit in the 2GB RAM. So it has to be somewhere, even if deleted. I don't think that before shutting down the tablet would be like *wait first I'm going to delete this video the guy was recording all that time*, that's just ridiculous.

Comment: Yes you should look in any temp location (not nessisarily called temp) for a large file item that could have a corrupt ending on it, and could be a corrupted file, unlike .part files which could have been closed proper even if incomplete. What software was being used? Many recording softwares will be using a specific recording folder for the streaming record , but store the final where the user selected, after the file is "closed". An abrupt ending of the record, would leave a partial (could be  corrupted) file hanging out, the system may class it corrupt on a disk scan

Comment: @Psycogeek thanks for yor reply. That was a default (pre-installed) Windows 8 camera app.

Comment: search for `datemodified:yesterday size:gigantic` (gigantic = >128M) returned nothing

Comment: Well no info on the web pointing to a location other than the camera roll folder in the users library stuff.   To know more would be to start a record, and observe disk in the resource monitor.

Comment: I did think about that, but wouldn't this overwrite the lost file in case it was deleted? (and I think that's what happened). I'm now trying to run a deleted file recovery program.

Comment: yes, if the system just tossed it.  Do you know if they system would have shut-down proper on battery low? or is it normal for your system to slam off when it runs out?